# hide lines with run and markdown button on .ipynb on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

**versions**
Windows 10 Home version 2004
Visual Studio Code: 1.48.2
Python Extension on VSCode: v2020.8.105045

I want to hide the lines with "run button and markdown button" on every cell that are shown when I open .ipynb on Visual Studio Code (the area inside the red frame on the image below).
I want to do so because I don't need these buttons.
Is there any way to do this? If so, could you tell me how to do it?
Thanks in advance!

[notebook cell. I want to hide the inside of the red frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNvct.png)

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do this as well. Very annoying.